# Using nested WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ymd, 
       creative_id, 
       sum(imps) as imps, 
       sum(booked_revenue_dollars) as booked_rev
  FROM agg_dw_advertiser_publisher_analytics_adjusted
 WHERE buyer_member_id=456
   AND (sum(imps) > 500 WHERE ymd > current_date() - 14) #this part is wrong
 GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING min(ymd) < current_date() - 14
 ORDER BY 2,1 ASC;
```

ymd = year/month/date

I'm trying to filter out `creative_id`'s where the sum of the field `imps` is less than 500 in aggregate over the past 2 weeks. I'm obviously not doing this right, but have tried as an additional `HAVING` clause as well as a sub query. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept called **Nested WHERE** . You can modify your `HAVING` like this.

```
SELECT creative_id, 
       sum(imps) as imps, 
       sum(booked_revenue_dollars) as booked_rev
  FROM agg_dw_advertiser_publisher_analytics_adjusted
 WHERE buyer_member_id=456
 GROUP BY creative_id
HAVING sum(imps) > 500 AND min(ymd) > current_date() - 14
 ORDER BY 2,1 ASC;
```

Comment: The Group by as written here will not give him the right sum. He will need a subquery I believe to be able to keep selecting ymd.

Comment: I think `ymd` is not important in select list because the driver is `creative_id`

Comment: agreed but the OP needs to see if he needs historical data (keep ymd) or not :)

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli I don't think this will return the correct info. Wouldn't this merely filter to show days (ymd) that had less than 500 imps? I need to know which creative_id's had less than 500 imps in total over the span of the previous 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (off the top of my head)

```
SELECT ymd, creative_id, 
       sq.imps as imps,
       sq.booked_rev as booked_rev
  FROM agg_dw_advertiser_publisher_analytics_adjusted a
  INNER JOIN 
      (
       SELECT creative_id, sum(imps) as imps, sum(booked_revenue_dollars) as booked_rev
       FROM agg_dw_advertiser_publisher_analytics_adjusted
       WHERE buyer_member_id=456 and ymd > current_date() - 14
       GROUP BY creative_id
      ) as sq
    ON  a.creative_id = sq.creative_id
 WHERE buyer_member_id=456 and sq.imps > 500 and ymd > current_date() - 14
 ORDER BY ymd,creative_id ASC;
```

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow. Thanks.